How do vertically align text in Bootstrap card?
I have a set/series of Bootstrap cards where each card has an image and then body text. Each of my images are different dimensions, so I set them to have a max-height of 100px. However, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way for the text in all the cards to begin at a consistent height - right now the text just starts at the height wherever the image ends.
In other words, I want all the body text to be aligned to an invisible "top" below the image, regardless of each card's image height. Kind of like this question.
iv
            class="col-md-4 col-12 p-3 d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center align-items-start card-container"
          >
            <!-- Card START -->
            <div
              class="card mx-3 h-100 d-flex flex-column"
              style="max-width: 10rem"
            >
              <img
                class="card-img-top p-3"
                src="imgs/pic1.svg"
                alt="Card 1"
                style="object-fit: cover; height: auto; max-width: 100%"
              />
              <div class="card-body mt-auto">
                <h5 class="card-title fs-6 text-center">Text</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Card END -->
            <!-- Card START -->
            <div
              class="card mx-3 h-100 d-flex flex-column"
              style="max-width: 10rem"
            >
              <img
                class="card-img-top p-2"
                src="imgs/pic2.png"
                alt="Card 2"
                style="object-fit: cover; height: auto; max-width: 100%"
              />
              <div class="card-body mt-auto">
                <h5 class="card-title fs-6 text-center">Text</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Card END -->
          </div>

I've tried everything I can think of and started asking ChatGPT without any help. Does anyone know if this is doable in Bootstrap?
Edit: not sure why this was closed. This question relates to Bootstrap not self-styling via CSS

Have you looked at the answers there?
